# How to add the UserManager via Dependency Injection in AspNet.Core 2.1?

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-webapi

I've created an Asp.Net Core 2.1 Web Api that uses Bearer Token authentication using Identity Server 4.  I have two db contexts, one that is for identity and one that is my data access for my custom application.  I want to be able to use the UserManager and UserStore in my Web Api using dependency injection in my controllers.

The problem is that once I add in the "relevant" code for DI, my controller methods are throwing a 302 and trying to redirect me to a login URL.  It's like my bearer authentication is being overridden.  Below is what my Startup.cs looks like. Any thoughts on how this should be done?

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {

        string connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;

        services.AddDbContext<CustomContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

        // start of the stuff that should add the usermanager and userstore
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));


        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        // end of the stuff

        services.AddMvcCore()
            .AddAuthorization()
            .AddJsonFormatters();

        services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "http://authenticate.com";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                options.ApiName = "api1";
            });

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            // this defines a CORS policy called "default"
            options.AddPolicy("default", policy =>
            {
                policy.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowCredentials();
            });
        });


    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseCors("default");
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

The controllers look like this:

```
public class PlayerController : BaseApiController
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;

    public PlayerController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager)
    {
        userManager = _userManager;
    }
    .....
 }
```

With BaseApiController like this:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[Authorize]
public class BaseApiController : Controller
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Could you update the code you use in controller

Comment: You don't need do anything special, except to add `UserManager<T>` to your controllers constructor. Everything else is already in place when you use Identity. Could it be that you are using MVC Controllers and your Error View/Action requires authentication?!

Comment: Also please keep in mind, its advised to have Authentication **AFTER** CORS registration. You don't want get CORS errors for users who are not logged in

Comment: @ngohungphuc I've added in the controller code.

Comment: @Tseng Until I added in the new code, if it throws an error, it will just throw a 500 out to the WebApi (or if it dies in initialization a 502).  So it doesn't require authentication to present an error message.  Currently the CORS and Bearer authentication aren't interacting - if my token expires or I don't provide one,  I get a 401 as expected.  I get a CORS error from run time errors, which I don't currently view as an issue, since it's already not doing what it was supposed to.

Comment: Well, if you put `[Authorize]` on your base controller and the and the controller with `Error` action derives from it, it is protected unless it has `[AllowAnonymous]`. I've never seen another reason for redirect to login unless you're not authorized or manually send the authorize challenge result from a controller

Comment: Also since you are getting redirect to login rather than `401` status code (and no redirect) it suggests you are using the wrong authentication scheme. WebApi controllers shouldn't redirect, that's only for MVC (controllers which return views)

Comment: @Tseng Yes exactly, which is what I've already said above. If I remove the code that supposedly adds the DI

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

Everything performs as it should, I get a 401 if my authentication is no longer valid.  Adding in the "DI code" gives me a 302 redirect, which means that it is overriding my Bearer authentication.  I want to add UserManager without creating another layer of authentication.

Comment: Sorry, now I think I know whats your issue. The "UserManager" bits were a bit misleading

Comment: IdentityServer and your WebAPI are not within the same application, correct?  If they are separate applications, you don't need ASP.NET Core Identity in your WebApi project, only the `AddIdentityServerAuthentication` call. if its same application (not recommended), then you need to integrate ASP.NET Core Identity with IdSrv4 as [per docs](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/6_aspnet_identity.html#configure-identityserver)

Comment: @Tseng No they aren't the same application.  Not sure I understand how the UserManager bits are misleading.  I want to use DI to access the UserManager so that I can manage my users via UserManager operations not via my own db context.  The additional authentication that "services.AddIdentity" is creating is an unwanted side effect.

Comment: When they aren't the same application, then you don't have identity in the same application. ASP.NET Core Identity isn't meant to be a shared library to access its data from different applications. Identity is meant to be managed by the application which acts as Identity authority. Thats why you get this odd issues. Your only way would be to register the dependencies yourself, but I would advise against it because this way you bypass security and settings set by the identity server

Comment: And you are at higher security risk if your api server gets hacked, the attacker also has access to your identity database. Also if you change security settings (stronger password policy), then it won't apply to the resource apps (WebApi apps who use the core identity to authenticate and grant access to its resources), since the passwords & stuff can also be changed from the. i.e. if you change password from the 2nd app, it may use outdated (and less secure) settings. Really, only the core identity server should have the power own and change this data, no other applications. bad app design

Comment: And _misleading_ in the sense as it sounds that injecting the `UserManager` causes the issues, which isn't the case. Its the mixup of identity and jwt bearer auth

Comment: Ok... context would probably help.  Use case: I want to manage authentication and authorization from my IS4 application, but I want to manage the user profile from my custom application (a client).  Reason being that my IS4 server handles multiple clients, but the profiles are unique to each client application.  IS4 includes ProfileService, so to my thinking it makes sense to use the UserManager to manage the user's profile and not a custom dbContext.  For example, I care about First Name, Last Name and DoB in my custom application, but I don't care about it for the purposes of authentication.

Comment: I all agree with @Tseng

Answer (score 3):

`services.AddIdentity<TUser>()` adds an "unnecessary" authentication configuration since you already have a bearer scheme from the `services.AddAuthentication("Bearer").AddIdentityServerAuthentication()` configuration. Take a look at the code below for `AddIdentity()`. Notice how many schemes were also added (including cookie scheme).

```
public static IdentityBuilder AddIdentity<TUser, TRole>(
        this IServiceCollection services,
        Action<IdentityOptions> setupAction)
        where TUser : class
        where TRole : class
    {
        // Services used by identity
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme, o =>
        {
            o.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login");
            o.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
            {
                OnValidatePrincipal = SecurityStampValidator.ValidatePrincipalAsync
            };
        })
        .AddCookie(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme, o =>
        {
            o.Cookie.Name = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
            o.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        })
        .AddCookie(IdentityConstants.TwoFactorRememberMeScheme, o =>
        {
            o.Cookie.Name = IdentityConstants.TwoFactorRememberMeScheme;
            o.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
            {
                OnValidatePrincipal = SecurityStampValidator.ValidateAsync<ITwoFactorSecurityStampValidator>
            };
        })
        .AddCookie(IdentityConstants.TwoFactorUserIdScheme, o =>
        {
            o.Cookie.Name = IdentityConstants.TwoFactorUserIdScheme;
            o.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        });

        // cut for brevity

        return new IdentityBuilder(typeof(TUser), typeof(TRole), services);
    }
```

You dont need that. What you do need is:

```
services.AddIdentityCore<TUser>()
```

which does not add another authentication configuration.